# Iframe v/s external js (to show my website's content on other websites)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

In my project,

I have created a code snippet which can be copied and then put in any website. It shows my content on other websites.

What I am using now is :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var user = 'abc';
var age = '23';

document.write('<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com/page.php?user='+ user + '&age=' + age + '" ></iframe');
</script>
```

In page.php,

I do some processing based on `user` and `age` and show dynamic content.

My approach works fine.

But when I look into some good standard ways to do such tasks, I find a different way.

Take an example of google adsense code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var a = 'somedata';
 var b = 'someotherdata';
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/adsenseurl.js'></script>
```

I guess, since `a` and `b` are global; adsenseurl.js must be using it and may be finally they are showing it on iframe.

**So, now the question.**

What's the advantage in using google's approach and whats wrong in my approach ?

p.s. I know I should try to avoid using iframes but I dont see any other way to accomplish this.

Comment: there is no difference except the extension is likely fake or loads another script with the iframe in the adsense version and some server process is executed

Comment: @mplungjan google adsense links to an js file. So you dont have anything in favour of google's version. I should stick with my code. Right ?

Comment: @mplungjan Can you write your both suggestions in answer, so that I can mark it as answer ?

Comment: Just another (probably irrelevant) thought: why not simply ask the user to add `<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com/page.php?user=abc&age=23"></iframe>` to the DOM location of his choice?

Comment: Because we try to code assuming users are fools. They would find it hard to put values on querystring :) Believe me, this method looks hard to him :) Finally I've given him textboxes in which he/she can enter values and then a generate button which generates this code in textarea and a copy button which copies it ;)

Comment: @Jashwant It seems to me that you are making things more complex than they could be. But I'm not familiar with the peculiarities of your system and its implementation, so I'm not going to elaborate on this topic anymore in fear of giving an uneducated advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between your approach and adSense is in my opinion that your code has to be placed where the ads have to appear and loading a script like adsense, they can place the iframe in the DOM after examining the page - using

```
var myIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
.
.
someDOMObject.appendChild(myIframe);
```

and/or manipulating the zindex to float the iframe above the page

Lastly the iFrame is useful (regardless of "oh noes - iframes are evil" you may hear) since you can use any css and jquery you like. If the page you are on already has styled divs and old versions of jQuery you will have a lot more work to make it look like you want.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for 'they can place the iframe in the DOM after examining the page' . May be this is the reason behind google strategy. May be they do a lot of cross checks for illegitimate clicks and other things.

Answer (score 0):

Why use an iframe? If your user loads the `<script src='yoursite.com/something.js'></script>`, you immediately have access to his DOM and you can do whatever you want via that `something.js`. In the same way that you load jQuery from some CDN - it can be immediately used to modify the DOM.

Otherwise there's really no difference except that:

1. Instead of embedding a potentially big amount of code that your user has to maintain, he just provides the necessary variables and simply links to a script on your page.
2. You can update the js code on your server and make sure that *all* your users are immediately (minus caching) up-to-date with the new functionality.

There might be other advantages, but these two should suffice I believe.

Comment: Iframe gives me flexibility. I have css and js code in my page.php.

Comment: @Jashwant: You can still create an iFrame as in your example, if you really want to.  You just do it in a script on your server instead of inside a script block in the head of the user's page.  With the benefits above listed by Oleg. Maybe that's what Google is doing too, as you say.

Comment: @Jashwant: Instead of an iFrame, you could use jQuery ajax to load your site HTML into a div on the user's page.  You can then still apply any css and js defined in styles and scripts on your server specifically to your unique site elements, for example using $.getScript().

Comment: @Oleg 
1. User needs to put just one script tag in my case. And it doesnt have that much of data.
2. I can even update my page.php file on server and can be make sure that all my users are up do date with new functionality.

Comment: @Stefan I'll have to load jQuery library in my user's website. I dont think its a good way.

Comment: @Jashwant Who told you that `.js` files are static? :) Basically what you do is *mod_rewrite* `something.js` into `something.php` in your apache or nginx or whatever server and serve dynamic, personalized content. Now, if you want to serve css as well, just give the user two links: one to your `.js` file and another to your `.css` file, both being cleverly redirected to your php files.

Comment: @Stefan - the code you ajax in will be styled by css already in the page and you cannot count on the site you are on not already having jQuery or not or in a wrong/old version. iFrame is a safer choice

Comment: @Oleg Its all about ease to use. Why would I suggest them to load two files ? Also, may be my css could interfere with the user's page. Same with jQuery. Also I know.js files are not static :)

I agree with mplungjan.

Comment: @mplungjan: If you put a src link (to jQuery on a CDN) in a script tag, inside the 'cut and paste' code for the user, then you don't have to count on jQuery being loaded already.  And if you make sure your elements have unique ids and classes then you can (and must) easily override the site's own css.

Comment: @mplungian: Or from inside your script, you can dynamically, easily add script tags to the page if jQuery is not present, for example: `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
 var tag = document.createElement('script');  tag.src = url_jQuery_CDN;    tag.type = 'text/javascript'; etc. }`

Comment: If the site has `div { border:5px solid pink; float:right }` or such, then you have a hard time handling all such cases. And the site can have jQuery 1.3 and you need 1.4+ - what then?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm sorry, but your last argument is invalid. In the same way I could say that *"if the site has `iframe { display: none; }` or such, then you have a hard time handling all such cases"*.

Comment: @Oleg dont you think , possibility of lightening in your home is less than you eat burger today ?

Comment: @Jashwant I don't eat burgers, but I often see the "display" property of iframes set to "none" because the iframes are used as workarounds for long polling, javascript-initiated download of files, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: I guess we are commenting a lot. I have put my points. I liked mplungjan's suggestions. Answered it. It should end up now. 

My conclusion, make external js and create iframe in that. But I dont need that complexity and does not need any checkups. You should not do iframe display:none. If you polling, select a specific iframe rather than general one.

Comment: @Oleg iframe display none is less likely than old or no jQuery. I have written several bookmarklets for real-life use so I do know what I am talking about.